# Does user with more reputation get any profit?

Tags: discussion, reputation

What does reputation do except providing a different level of privilege?
What is it about? I find people competing for reputation in this askubuntu page.
Isn't this page about solving each others problem? Sometimes, I get pissed off with this.

Answer (score 9):

Makes you feel warm inside knowing you helped someone (many people the more rep), and they thought your help was useful :)

Comment: I might have gone another way...like - "clearly you don't understand what SE is about" still.  it's a nicer explanation

Comment: @Mateo I totally agree with you but for some user, I found it's about being in top, not only helping other. It makes me feel sad. Though, they may not mean this, but their response makes me think so.

Comment: @Habi - what question/answer specifically are you raging about?  put a finer point on it so we can fix it.

Comment: @hbdgaf I was just asked reason to change accepted answer. Isn't it obvious to change accepted answer after realizing other answer to be more appropriate.

Comment: Link, specifically...maybe someone would upvote your answer.  That counts more than an accept anyway (10 versus 2).  I'm trying to help you, but you won't let me.

Comment: So...  You are not really asking about rep... "Accepted" answer is the one you used - found to be correct, not not based on more comprehensive or better screenshots, forget about the rep reward - users are just trying to figure out what worked for you

Answer (score 2):

the more rep I get the more I know that I've done a good answer and something people find useful. It's also a competition the more rep you have the more people respect you on the site.

The reputation is a way for the site to show what users are writing the best answers/questions. It's a ranking system of sort.